# Disabling text input or filtering on show_quick_panel

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm currently using `show_quick_panel` from ST3's API for a plugin I'm working on and I'm trying to disable filtering or text input modification, but I've been looking through the API and I haven't been able to find anything in there, or any settings I could toggle to imitate that behavior. Am I overlooking anything, or is there a better alternative to what I'm doing?

This is the `example.py` plugin file in my Packages folder.

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class ExampleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        window = sublime.active_window()

        window.show_quick_panel(['alice', 'bob', 'carol'], None)
```

I can call it without any issue through the console:

```py
view.run_command("example")
```

And I get the following:

Immediately after running the command:
[image]

After typing from the keyboard:
[image]

The default behavior is that when the quick panel shows up (the menu with the text input field, and options `['alice', 'bob', 'carol']`), when the user types it enters the input text field and 'filters'/'searches' through the options (in the second picture, typing `"al"` filters the options down to just `['alice', 'carol']`).

What I'm trying to do is disable this behavior because my project depends on having each option available at all times when the quick panel is shown.

Comment: You haven't included any code, and your description is not very clear as to what you want to do. Please describe exactly what you mean by "filtering or text input modification." You also need some code. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I apologize for that; I've edited the main post to include screen shots and the code snippet.

Comment: You can not disable that behaviour. You could try using `show_popup_menu()` or `show_popup()` as an alternative to `show_quick_panel()`.